# Get real time geojson on Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I frequently need to obtain some info about coordinates, because I have dynamic elements on a map (in Openlayers). So I use SetInterval and XMLHttpRequest Object to do it.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var requestURL = "data.geojson";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            console.clear();
            console.log(request.response);
        }
    }
    var prueba = setInterval(function () {
        request.open('GET', requestURL, true);
        request.setRequestHeader('authenticated_user', 'terrain');
        request.send();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Is It the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [`readyState` 4 simply means XHR is done](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState). The response, however, can still either be a success (2xx) or a failure (4xx, 5xx). In order to distinguish a success from an error, you should also check [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status).

Next would be the reuse of the XHR instance. Although it's perfectly valid ([`open` reinitializes the instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)), you'll have to be absolutely sure subsequent calls aren't affected by the previous calls. It's probably much safer to just create a new instance of XHR for each request.

Then instead of `window.onload`, consider using `addEventListener`. The issue is that there might be other scripts assigning a callback to `window.onload`, overwriting your handler. On the other hand, multiple calls to `addEventListener` will just append handlers.

A simpler way to do it, assuming your target audience doesn't use legacy browsers, is [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It's essentially jQuery's `$.ajax` but natively implemented.

```
window.addEventListener('load', event => {
  setInterval(() => {
    fetch('data.geojson', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { authenticated_user: 'terrain' }
    }).then(() => {
      console.clear();
      console.log(request.response);
    })
  }, 2000)
})
```